# Delegate 'Func' does not take 0 arguments

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I'm attempting to Add a Column to a grid in MVC, now the first parameter of the Column method takes a string for the text. So I'm attempting to use a lambda function to retrieve a string from the bound object, this is what I have so far, however the compiler is returning a Delegate 'Func' does not take 0 arguments

```
g.AddActionColumn(((Func<User, string>)((x)=> {return x.CurrentApplication.Name;}))())
```

the grid is bound to a `IEnumerable<User>` and `CurrentApplication` is a Class called `Application`.

The signature of `AddActionColumn` is:

```
 public TbbGrid<TModel, TId> AddActionColumn(string linkText, 
    string action = null, string controller = null, string area = null, 
    bool usePreviousUrl = false, bool isVisible = true,
    Func<TModel, bool> condition = null, string cellCssClasses = null, 
    string linkCssClasses = null, string headerCssClasses = null, 
    string headerText = null, string emptyText = null, 
    string propertyName = null, bool isSortable = false, 
    string previousUrlOverride = null)
```

Comment: What is the signature of `AddActionColumn`?

Comment: I updated the original post with the Signature of AddActionColumn

Comment: You *really* need to do something about that function.  There's no way it should be accepting that many parameters.

Comment: What parameter are you expecting `x.CurrentApplication.Name` to fill in the `AddActionColumn` method?

Comment: LinkText is what it sould be filling

Comment: If you have a `user` object instantiated, you should simply be able to pass `user.CurrentApplication.Name` in as the `linkText` parameter.  I don't think lambda is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because `AddActionColumn` doesn't take a `Func<>` as its first parameter, it takes a `string`.

You can't just pass in something that returns a string when called as this API isn't designed that way.

Comment: I know that, what I'm trying to do is get the Func<> to return a string inline, which I know can be done. I just can't get it to accept the right number of paramaters

Comment: @Risryn What user to you expect to get the string from?

Comment: the user in the current row as the grid populates. if the function accepted a func<> I would just use x => x.CurrentApplication.Name

Comment: @Risryn - but the function **does not** accept a `Func<>`, so you cannot do this!

Comment: @Risryn But it doesn't.  It needs a string *right now*.  If you want to get a string from a user, you need to have a user *right now*.  If you don't, then you need to re-work the function to accept a delegate, rather than a string, if it is going to be the one to come up with the user.